# is it possible to d A/B testing for two different UI with Algolia and Instant-Search?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

We are using Algolia (Instant-Search) for searching in our React application. Now we would like to have a A/B testing to check different User Interfaces.

As far as I read from the documentations, A/B testing is possible for testing:

1. Test different index settings
2. Test different search parameters

So the question is it possible to d A/B testing for two different UI with Algolia?

Answer (score 0):

Algolia's A/B Testing feature is designed for relevance testing. It lets you select a strategy, redirects users to one of two configurations, and collects results via the Analytics and A/B Test APIs.

Even if you build your UI with one of Algolia's InstantSearch libraries, it's hosted on your hosting platform, so the A/B testing needs to happen at this level. For example, if you use Netlify, you can use their [Split Testing](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/split-testing/) feature to serve two different UIs, and send events to your analytics platform (Google Analytics, Segment, etc.) to determine which UI converts better.